# Linear algebra:P2 - orthonormal basis of V and $\mathbb{R^3}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

In $\mathbb{R}^3 $ with $ 
\underline{N}=
\begin{pmatrix} 
   1\\ 
   2\\
   1
\end{pmatrix} $

and the subspace $V={\underline{N}^\bot}$.

From [Linear Algebra:P1 - Dim(V), linear independence](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/349076/linear-algebrap1-dimv-linear-independence) follows:

(a1)The following vectors are linearly independent
(a2)dim(V)=2.

(a3)The following vectors are in V.

$\underline{x}_1=
\begin{pmatrix} 
   0\\ 
   1/2\\
   -1
\end{pmatrix}$ , 
$\underline{x}_2=
\begin{pmatrix} 
   1\\ 
   0\\
   -1
\end{pmatrix}$
 , 
$\underline{x}_3=
\begin{pmatrix} 
   1\\ 
   -1\\
   1
\end{pmatrix}$

(a4)Construct/built an orthonormal basis {$\underline{w}_1;\underline{w}_2$} of V with $\underline{v}_1$ and $\underline{v}_2$ by using the Gram–Schmidt process.


(a4)

1) $$\underline{v}_1:=\underline{x}_1 \ne \underline{0}$$


$$\underline{v}_1=
\begin{pmatrix}
1\\
2\\
0
\end{pmatrix}$$


$$\underline{w}_1= 
  \frac{ \underline{v}_1 }{\|\underline{v}_1\|}=
  \frac{2}{\sqrt{5}} \cdot
  \begin{pmatrix}
  0\\
  1/2\\
  -1
  \end{pmatrix}
$$

2)$$ \underline{v}_2:=\underline{x}_2- \frac{<\underline{x}_2;\underline{v}_1>}{<\underline{v}_1;\underline{v}_1>}\cdot \underline{v}_1$$


$$
\underline{v}_2:=
\begin{pmatrix}
1\\
0\\
-1
\end{pmatrix}-
\frac{\begin{pmatrix}
  1\\
  0\\
  -1
  \end{pmatrix}
 \cdot 
\begin{pmatrix}
  0\\
  1/2\\
  -1
  \end{pmatrix}}
{\begin{pmatrix}
  0\\
  1/2\\
  -1
  \end{pmatrix}
  \cdot
  \begin{pmatrix}
  0\\
  1/2\\
  -1
  \end{pmatrix}}
  \cdot
  \begin{pmatrix}
  0\\
  1/2\\
  -1
  \end{pmatrix}
$$


$$\underline{v}_2=
  \begin{pmatrix}
  1\\
  0\\
  -1
  \end{pmatrix}
  - \frac{4}{5}
\cdot
  \begin{pmatrix}
  0\\
  1/2\\
  -1
  \end{pmatrix}
  =
  \begin{pmatrix}
  1\\
  -2/5\\
  -1/5
  \end{pmatrix}
$$

$$\underline{w}_2= 
  \frac{ \underline{v}_2 }{\|\underline{v}_2\|}=
  \frac{1}{\sqrt{6}} \cdot
  \begin{pmatrix}
  1\\
  -2/5\\
  -1/5
  \end{pmatrix}
$$

So that {$\underline{w}_1;\underline{w}_2$} are an orthonormal basis of V.


(a5)Extend {$\underline{w}_1;\underline{w}_2$} to an orthonormal basis for $\mathbb{R^3}$


My questions are:

Is my approach correct for (a4)?

Have I done any mistake?

For (a5), how can I extend it, shall I take $\underline{x}_3$ and calculate with this one $\underline{w_3}$ by $$\underline{w}_3= 
  \frac{\underline{v}_3}{\|\underline{v}_3\|}$$

or is there another approach, perhaps by using $\underline{N}$, and if it is,

 why is it this way?

Comment: To check if you have an orthonormal set, you do the inner product between the elements in your set. If the inner product is 0 and every element has norm 1, then you have an orthonormal set. For your second question, have you heard of the Replacement lemma? A corollary to it is that you can extend a set to be a basis of a vector space V, provided that set is linearly independent.